# How do I change each slide's data- attribute without setting every slide to one background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on adding specific `data-` attributes to my slideshow so I can add custom backgrounds for each slide. What I do is add the custom data attribute, then assign the value to a variable using jQuery. After that, I pass the variable to the `.css()` and assign it to the `background` property.

```js
var elementSection = $(".cycle-slideshow section")),
    sectionBackground = elementSection.attr("data-cycle-slide-background");

$(elementSection).css({background: sectionBackground});
```

```html
<section data-cycle-slide-background="url(images/slides/laptopgreenery.jpg)"></section>
<section data-cycle-slide-background="url(images/slides/slide1bg.jpg)"></section>
<section data-cycle-slide-background="url(images/slides/slide2bg.png) repeat;" data-cycle-hash="2"></section>
```

However, doing it this way sets every slide's background to the one in the attribute, in this case "laptopgreenery.jpg".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop over each slide:

```
elementSection.each(function() {
    $(this).css('background', $(this).data('cycle-slide-background'));
});
```

Important: make sure you don't have `;` at the end of data attributes, it will make rule invalid and it will not be applied.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vetnLr8n/

Comment: Thank you. This also sets the first slide's background but leaves the other's blank.

Comment: Check the demo I posted. Also make sure you don't have `;` at the end of data attributes.

Comment: Many thanks. It was the semicolons that were making it not work. I didn't know adding them in would break it.

Answer (score 0):

You can taked advantage of the anonymous function available to the `css()` method; inside of which `$(this) refers to the current slide):

```
$(elementSection)
    .css({
        background: function() {
           return $(this).data('cycle-slide-background');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but all it does is set the first slides background and leave the rest blank.

Comment: Then you tried it wrong; or you forgot to set the `data` attribute. Can you reproduce that behaviour with a demo?